# Why are my icons in the task bar no longer working?

Tags: windows-10, desktop

Nothing works in the task bar at the bottom.  They did day before yesterday and not today.  Nothing on the right works including the calendar that opens if you click the time.  I cannot get Cortana to recognize being clicked.  And the Start menu is not functioning.  This means even shutdown is not available.. please help quickly.  Weather is not great and I do not leave my system on and leave if the weather is bad.  I am a novice so please do not speak computerize.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting Windows explorer.  Open up task manager `ctrl + alt + del`, find the Windows explorer process in the list (you may need to expand More Details), click on the process, and press restart in the bottom right, or end the task, and click File in the top left, select run new task, and type in `explorer.exe` to start Windows Explorer again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some things got gunked up.

I think the simplest way to resolve your issue would be to restart - since you indicated the start menu is not working, here is another way you can restart.

At the same time push the windows key and then push R.  This will bring up the run dialog box.  In this box type "shutdown -r" without the quotes and your computer should restart :)  Once it boots back up hopefully everything is functioning again.